# .NET LINQ left join issue

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I have an issue with trying to query and left join two DataTable objects.  Let me say for starters, yes - it's stupid that I have to do it in the first place. It'd be much easier to left join in a query, but I'm stuck with the constraint of only being able to query one table out of SAP at a time. So, here's my issue. I've been able to retrieve two DataTable objects from SAP, and I've added debug messages and verified that there are thousands of records in each table.  I need to left join the detail table (dtDtl) to the balance table (dtBal) based on 6 key columns, if detail records exist.

Here is the section of code that I'm trying to get working:

```
'Call the GetData() function to return a DataTable
Me.fieldList = {"BUKRS", "RACCT", "KOSTL", "PRCTR", "RYEAR", "POPER", "HSL", "ENTERED_DATE"}
Me.tblName = "ZTTRAIL_BALANCE"
Dim dtBal As DataTable = GetData()
dtBal.TableName = tblName

'Call the GetData() function to return a DataTable
Me.fieldList = {"BUKRS", "RACCT", "KOSTL", "PRCTR", "RYEAR", "POPER", "HSL", "LIFNR", "NAME1", "BUDAT", "BLDAT", "BLART", "ENTERED_DATE"}
Me.tblName = "ZTTRAIL_BAL_GRAN"
Dim dtDtl As DataTable = GetData()
dtDtl.TableName = tblName
             
'Create a DataTable to return
Dim dtJoined As New DataTable
dtJoined.Columns.Add("BUKRS", GetType(String))
dtJoined.Columns.Add("RACCT", GetType(String))
dtJoined.Columns.Add("KOSTL", GetType(String))
dtJoined.Columns.Add("PRCTR", GetType(String))
dtJoined.Columns.Add("RYEAR", GetType(String))
dtJoined.Columns.Add("POPER", GetType(String))
dtJoined.Columns.Add("HSL", GetType(Decimal))
dtJoined.Columns.Add("LIFNR", GetType(String))
dtJoined.Columns.Add("NAME1", GetType(String))
dtJoined.Columns.Add("BUDAT", GetType(String))
dtJoined.Columns.Add("BLDAT", GetType(String))
dtJoined.Columns.Add("BLART", GetType(String))
dtJoined.Columns.Add("ENTERED_DATE", GetType(String))

Dim result = 
            (From balRow In dtBal.AsEnumerable() _
            Group Join dtlRow In dtDtl.AsEnumerable() _
            On New With {
                .BUKRS = balRow.Field(Of String)("BUKRS"),
                .RACCT = balRow.Field(Of String)("RACCT"),
                .KOSTL = balRow.Field(Of String)("KOSTL"),
                .PRCTR = balRow.Field(Of String)("PRCTR"),
                .RYEAR = balRow.Field(Of String)("RYEAR"),
                .POPER = balRow.Field(Of String)("POPER")
            } Equals New With {
                .BUKRS = dtlRow.Field(Of String)("BUKRS"),
                .RACCT = dtlRow.Field(Of String)("RACCT"),
                .KOSTL = dtlRow.Field(Of String)("KOSTL"),
                .PRCTR = dtlRow.Field(Of String)("PRCTR"),
                .RYEAR = dtlRow.Field(Of String)("RYEAR"),
                .POPER = dtlRow.Field(Of String)("POPER")
            } Into joinedData = Group _
            From joinedRecords In joinedData.DefaultIfEmpty() _
            Select New With {
                BUKRS = balRow.Field(Of String)("BUKRS"),
                RACCT = balRow.Field(Of String)("RACCT"),
                KOSTL = balRow.Field(Of String)("KOSTL"),
                PRCTR = balRow.Field(Of String)("PRCTR"),
                RYEAR = balRow.Field(Of String)("RYEAR"),
                POPER = balRow.Field(Of String)("POPER"),
                HSL = If(joinedRecords Is Nothing, balRow.Field(Of Decimal)("HSL"), joinedRecords.Field(Of Decimal)("HSL")),
                LIFNR = If(joinedRecords Is Nothing, " ", joinedRecords.Field(Of String)("LIFNR")),
                NAME1 = If(joinedRecords Is Nothing, " ", joinedRecords.Field(Of String)("NAME1")),
                BUDAT = If(joinedRecords Is Nothing, " ", joinedRecords.Field(Of String)("BUDAT")),
                BLDAT = If(joinedRecords Is Nothing, " ", joinedRecords.Field(Of String)("BLDAT")),
                BLART = If(joinedRecords Is Nothing, " ", joinedRecords.field(Of String)("BLART")),
                ENTERED_DATE = If(joinedRecords Is Nothing, balRow.Field(Of String)("ENTERED_DATE"), joinedRecords.Field(Of String)("ENTERED_DATE"))
            }
            ).Select(
                Function(x)
                    Dim row As DataRow = dtJoined.NewRow()
                    row("BUKRS") = x.BUKRS
                    row("RACCT") = x.RACCT
                    row("KOSTL") = x.KOSTL
                    row("PRCTR") = x.PRCTR
                    row("RYEAR") = x.RYEAR
                    row("POPER") = x.POPER
                    row("HSL") = x.HSL
                    row("LIFNR") = x.LIFNR
                    row("NAME1") = x.NAME1
                    row("BUDAT") = x.BUDAT
                    row("BLDAT") = x.BLDAT
                    row("BLART") = x.BLART
                    row("ENTERED_DATE") = x.ENTERED_DATE
                    Return row
                End Function
            )
```

I've read a bunch of posts on Group Joins and LINQ, and just still can't get the syntax right.  Can someone help me out with what I'm missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Your final `Select New With` is invalid syntax.

Comment: I believe your code is fine, except you haven't realized that anonymous objects in VB.Net do not have value equality semantics by default. You need to proceed each field definition on the two sides of the `Equals` with `Key` to indicate to VB.Net they should be compared for equality by value and not ignored.